# ¿Qué significa la expresión "a ojo de buen cubero"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Una expresión común aquí en México es "**a ojo de buen cubero**". Ejemplo:

> A: ¿Cuantas personas crees que hay en esta conferencia?
>
> B: A ojo de buen cubero unas 500 personas.

¿Cúal es su significado? ¿Por qué el uso de la palabra "[cubero](http://dle.rae.es/cubero)"?

Comment: También se usa en España. De hecho pensaba que era exclusivo de España, pero parece que algo más amplio. Veamos si en Sudamérica o Centroamérica también se emplea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se refiere a que cuando le preguntas a alguien un dato y la otra persona no lo sabe y tiene que hacer un cálculo aproximado:

Por ejemplo:

> - Cuántos kilómetros faltan para llegar?
> - No lo se.
> - A ojo de buen cubero / Ahí más o menos calcúlale.

Se puede usar en otros contextos, por ejemplo en la cocina cuando la receta dice 235 gramos de algún ingrediente y no tienes báscula pues agregas el ingrediente "a ojo de buen cubero" es decir más o menos calculando los 235 gramos.

[Aquí](http://erasmusv.wordpress.com/2007/10/04/a-ojo-de-buen-cubero/) encontré este blog que explica más a detalle el origen de esta expresión:

> Una cuba era una cubeta que se usaba para guardar líquidos y el cubero
>   era el artesano que fabricaba cubas.
>
> Al hacerlo de manera artesanal, sin usar instrumentos para medir o
>   máquinas especiales "a ojo" tenía que hacer que todas las cubas fueran
>   del mismo tamaño.

Estaba seguro que esa expresión era de origen mexicano, pero al leer el blog me doy cuenta que su origen es español. Todos aprendemos algo todos los días :)

Comment: Los enlaces son buenos, aunque preferimos copiar o parafrasear algún punto relevante del mismo ya que el sitio original puede dejar de existir.

Comment: @JoulSauron Después de comer es más duro pensar :D Aquí dejo tu gran recomendación, comentario útil :D: Además de "a ojo de buen cubero" también existe la palabra "ojímetro" que se utiliza para lo mismo

Comment: @Sergio Romero Edita un poco el documento y queda perfecto :)

Comment: Siempre es mejor utilizar fuentes fiables. Ese blog es de un aficionado cualquiera y no cita ninguna fuente. Su explicación de que "todas las cubas fueran del mismo tamaño" no me parece correcta. En mi respuesta cito un artículo de "El País" donde se entrevista a un cubero.

Answer (score 11):

La expresión "a ojo de buen cubero" significa:

> "Aproximadamente, al tanteo; pero con bastante precisión"

Y proviene de:

> "La maestría con la que los cuberos calculaban "sin matemática alguna"
>   el número de duelas para cerrar la circunferencia. Por eso, no hay
>   siempre las mismas (en una barrica entre 28 y 32) ni tienen la misma
>   anchura".

Fuente: "[Ojo, queda un buen cubero](http://elpais.com/diario/2010/11/21/domingo/1290315156_850215.html)" - Artículo de "El País" (periódico español)

Answer (score -1):

Creo que el tiempo a distorsionado el origen y confundido la palabra "cubero" con la palabra "tubero", tubero es un oficio muy viejo y es la persona que se dedica a instalar tuberías industriales (ojo, no plomero), y este utiliza la vista para alinear de forma casi perfecta los tubos y accesorios en determinada instalación de tuberías, de ahí sale la frase " a ojo de buen tubero" sin embargo la gente que no sabe lo que es un tubero cambia la palabra por cubero.

Comment: Creo que, aunque este post sea válido como una posible respuesta, es muy poco probable que esa conjetura sea cierta (especialmente viendo lo que ya aportan otras contribuciones, como dice Walen en su comentario) y por lo tanto va a obtener votos negativos. La cosa mejoraría si pudieses aportar alguna referencia o dato sobre ese cambio de "tubero" a "cubero" que lo abale de forma formal. De lo contrario esto es solo una conjetura que intenta responder a la pregunta, cierto, pero que es muy poco probable que sea el auténtico origen de la expresión.